# Позиционирование inline-block`а

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```css
i {
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 flex: 1 1 384px;
}
```

```html
<i>Icon</i>
<ul>
  <a href="">
    <li>Link</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li>Link</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li>Link</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Помогите позиционировать элемент i чтобы список не поднимался наверх

Comment: Слово `Icon` должен быть прямо на верку `Link`?

Comment: у вас невалидная структура для списка - должно быть ul > li, т.е у li всегда родителем должен быть ul

Comment: Тебе бы валидатор кучу ошибок выдал за твой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляя элементу св-во `float` вы автоматически делаете его блочным.

Чтобы очистить обтекание, добавьте следующему элементу `clear:both;`.

Как выше в комментариях отметили - такая верстка **не валидна**, за `ul` должен следовать `li`.

Вот пример:

```css
i {
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
}
ul>li {
  clear:both;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 384px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<i>Icon</i>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала у тебя структура неверная, как сказал **soledar10**:

> у вас невалидная структура для списка - должно быть ul > li, т.е у li всегда родителем должен быть ul – soledar10

Так что вот так:

```css
i {display: inline-block; float: right; margin: 20px}
ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; width: 100%; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around;}
```

```html
<i>Icon</i>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
```